# How to Access Related Models in Polymorphic Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

If I have a polymorphic association, how do I access related methods in my views?

For example, let's say the model associations are:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :orderable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, :as => :orderable
end
```

And, in the `Order` view, I tried using:

```
<%= @order.product.id %>
```

But, that doesn't work. How do you access related models in the views then?

EDIT: Here's the form I'm using:

```
<% form_for [@orderable, @order] do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And then, I'm including it in the Product Show view, like this:

```
<%= render 'orders/form' %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

Use the name given to the `:as` to access the parent:

```
<%= @order.orderable.id %>
```

Also, [here is some info in the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It says that orderable is nil and throws an error when I tried that. Also, my routes aren't nested either, if that makes a difference?

Comment: Check if there is in fact an association present i.e. `orderable` is probably nil. Also you can use `@order.inspect`.

Comment: Hmm, yes, that's it. For some reason orderable_type and orderable_id aren't being populated by the form. Do you need to manually define those with hidden fields in the form or are they supposed to be automatically generated by passing the array `[@orderable, @order]` in the form? Also, it's in a partial that's being called in another controller's view (if that makes a difference). Thanks for the help too! Specifically, the Order form is a partial present in the Product Show view.

Comment: It should be automatic. Are you using `fields_for` to render the fields for the `Order` ?

Comment: I added the form I'm using. Basically, all the fields within it are hidden fields. I'm not sure what you mean by `fields_for`? Should that be something like `<% fields_for @product.order do |po| %>` and then the rest of the form?

Comment: `fields_for` nests the fields for a related model in the parent model. Check that when the params are received after a form submit, are the fields for order received within the params hash for `Product`: eg. `product=>{ order => {...}, ..other product fields...}`. If not, you either need to do it manually in the form or use `fields_for`. Oh, just noticed your form. I haven't used that style(`[..,..]`) before.. :). But note that `form_for` cannot be nested - i.e. a `<form>` cannot be containing a `<form>`. That's why `fields_for` exists..

Comment: I don't understand where to put the `fields_for` though? The `Order` object has one field, `price`. So, would I just put the `<% fields_for @product.order do |po| %>` right after the `form_for` tag?

Comment: Just to update this task for anyone else: I ended up using a `hidden_field_tag` to pass the `loan.id` from the `Transaction` partial in my `Service` view. Then, in the controller's create action, I built in the Service object to the Transaction and it works perfectly! Much more elegant than nil fields!

Answer (score 1):

Might want to check out the [Railscast by Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association). Should teach you everything you need to know about Polymorphic Associations.

Comment: Yes, I just watched that :) They kept it very simple in that example, and didn't cover accessing specific attributes in other models. IE: they covered how to access Comments in Articles but not Articles in Comments.

Comment: Look at what Zabba's answer is. Might help you.